# Unit test createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently implementing a mobile app integrated with Firebase. I have a method to create a user with an email and password, however, I want to unit test this functionality without calling the real method (so ideally through mocking). Is this possible?

```html
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Registration unsuccsesful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried mocking FirebaseAuth?

Comment: I have actually, and managed to get some tests working